# How to leave cells empty in Date column instead of writing DateTime.Min in EPPlus

Tags: epplus, epplus-4

I need to write a formatted date to Excel using EPPlus, leaving empty cells where there are no dates to write.  I have tried the following:

1. Writing a date, and then formatting it. This works unless I have no date, in which case the minimum value is written:

[image]

2. Formatting the date as a string (passing an empty string when there is no date), then assigning a custom format. [The problem with this is that Excel doesn't see the type as a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816043/epplus-date-cell-datatype-not-working), therefore a downstream system cannot use it:

[image]

How can I write dates to Excel, using EPPlus, where the dates are recognised as date types (not strings), but where missing date values are not written at all?

Comment: If you are doing a cast then you are probably entering 0's in the cells without dates.  Post your code so other can take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the data you bind to the date column is of type `DateTime?` (nullable).
Only if you provide a `null` value, an empty column will be rendered.

For example:

```
// Date format on first column
sheet.Column(1).Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy-mm-dd";

// Some date values
var columnValues = new List<DateTime?> {
    DateTime.Now,
    null,
    DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) };

// Bind values to column
sheet.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromArrays(columnValues.Select(v => new object[] { v }));
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you - I'll give this a try.

Comment: Thanks, I've not had a chance to try it, but I think this answer will work. I'll accept on that basis.