# Formating Specific Columns Using Epplus Not Saving

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm using EPPlus and iterating through all the columns of each worksheet in a workbook.  I'm trying to format every column with a header that contains the word "NUMBER" as a number format.  It runs and it hits the breakpoint where I set the number format but, when I open the spreadsheet, the columns are still formatted as text.  Any help would very much be appreciated.

```
    private void cleanSpreadSheet(string fileName)
    {
        // set all columns with a header of number to numeric type
        FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo(fileName);
        var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile);

        ExcelWorkbook wb = package.Workbook;

        foreach (ExcelWorksheet workSheet in wb.Worksheets)
        {
            var start = workSheet.Dimension.Start;
            var end = workSheet.Dimension.End;
            for (int col = start.Column; col <= end.Column; col++)
            { // col by col
                if (workSheet.Cells[1, col].Text.ToUpper().Contains("NUMBER"))
                {
                    workSheet.Column(col).Style.Numberformat.Format = "0";                         
                }

            }
        }
        package.Save();
        package.Dispose();
        wb.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: If you have to call Dispose on an object, that's a code smell. More likely, you should be using a [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

Comment: I believe what you want to do is set the column's data type, not set the format. I believe EPPlus determines that based on the type of the object that you are setting the row's value equal to. See [this question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816043/epplus-date-cell-datatype-not-working) for an example.

Comment: To expand on what @mason said, if the existing workbook cell contents are "Text", you'll probably have to do an int.Parse / double.Parse and replace the cell content with "Numbers"

Comment: @sfm - that would that mean I would have to iterate through the rows and change each cell in the column, right?

Comment: @Missy - that's what I was thinking, but I haven't tested it to see if that's the issue. You probably also should use double.TryParse or use a try/catch around each type conversion for each row.

Comment: @sfm - Please post your response as an answer.  That was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue may be that your existing Excel workbook has data formatted as Excel "Text". If this is the case, you won't likely be able to simply convert each cells' format to a number as Excel doesn't know how to convert "Text" to "Numbers".

Instead, you may need to iterate over each column and row in EPPlus and replace each value after casting them. The code below could use some error checking on the casts, but gives you a sense of the concept.

`//foreach row ... foreach column...
 ExcelRange cell = worksheet.Cells[row, col];
 cell.Value = double.Parse((string)cell.Value);`